# Where can I find LDraw files to download for basic figures?

Tags: building, ldraw

I would like to have a collection of simple examples for my youngsters.

Only for basic LEGO bricks. Not Technics or complex and complete space stations, just some
step-by-step instructions for the basic bricks. Based on the starters edition from LEGO.

I was thinking of: houses, small animals, simple aeroplane, simple car, tree, ...
All based on the basic instructions.

This would help the children a lot in playing.

***See the pictures. I would love to find step-by-step instructions in LDraw.***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will by definition have a lot of links, but here we go. Since you're looking for instructions there are a few sites that you should consider visiting.

The first is [Cubiculus](http://www.cubiculus.com/), which specializes in creating LDraw versions of custom and official instructions. The creator of the site adds plenty of his own (basic) instructions.

The second is [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/). It contains many creations by various builders, and some provide LDraw files for you to download. The instructions are usually quite advanced, however.

Lastly, you could put together your own LDraw files from LEGOs basic sets. The biggest consolidated collection of instructions is available on [Swooshable](http://swooshable.com/buildingschool/official-lego-instructions). (Full disclosure - it's my own scraper that consolidates set instructions from the five biggest sources on the web. I built it to not have to check different sites for a particular instruction.)

Hopefully that'll get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [LEGO Club Magazine](http://www.lego.com/en-gb/club/member/digital-magazines) - available online and through the post in some countries too - they have three editions:

1. Green Brick - Junior builders, probably what you're looking for at this stage
2. Yellow Brick - Mostly Friends/Elves focused, but with some City/other
3. Red Brick - Mostly City/Chima/Bionicle, but with some others as well

All of these contain stories, activities and one or two building instructions for something that can usually be built with basic bricks.

Comment: In 2017, it was rebranded as **LEGO Life Magazine**. Recent issues (PDF) can be found here: https://www.lego.com/en-gb/life/magazine/archive